# storing fields in Java ee websocket

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, java-ee-7

i have created a javaee websocket endpoint using a [PathParam](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/websocket/server/PathParam.html). The parameter and the session are each stored in a field @OnOpen.

The websocket listens to some event and send some data out to session (using the path parameter).

The problem is that both fields are null at the moment event is caught. What is the cause of this? Are there multiple instances of endpoint per session? I read the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Endpoint.html) : "If the developer uses the default ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator, there will be precisely one endpoint instance per active client connection. "
Here is example code:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/allbookings/{projectId}", encoders = {JSONEncoder.class},
                configurator = WebSocketUserConfig.class)
public class BookingsByProject {

    private Session session;
    private String  projectId;

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session, EndpointConfig conf, @PathParam(PROJECT_ID_KEY) String projectId) {
        if(projectId!=null){
            this.session = session;
            this.projectId = projectId;
        } else {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
        log.debug("Session closed.");
    }

    public void createdEventFired(@Observes @Created Booking entity) {
        if(session.isOpen){
            session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(converter.from(null, repo.getBookingsByProjectId(projectId)));
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that on createdEventFired session and projectId are always null! Why?

For sake of completeness here the configurator (only addin a user property):

```
public class WebSocketUserConfig extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {
    /**
     * Key used in config to mark if requesting user is admin.
     */
    public static final String IS_ADMIN_ADMIN = "isAdmin";

    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
        config.getUserProperties().put(IS_ADMIN_ADMIN, request.isUserInRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name()));
        super.modifyHandshake(config, request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? (Simplified) endpoint code + handshake request dump, etc..

Comment: you'll need to post your configurator as well. IT seems like the "session is null" issue is caused by not sharing the same instance with CDI and Tyrus - I don't see any CDI annotation on the endpoint class, so the event will be most likely called on different instance. (just add "System.out.print("XXX " + this)" and see what will be logged). The PathParam are you sure it is null? It seems like it might be ok in @OnOpen method and the issue you have is only about first problem..

Comment: my main question is: spec says there is only one instance per session(=active client connection)! the configurator does only set a user property - i'll add the code above

Comment: one instance per session is still valid even in your case - the problem is that CDI event is fired outside of that scope - (there is no @WebSocketSessionScoped or anything like that, unfortunately) - so CDI will create new instance, because it does know anything about websocket/Tyrus..

Comment: but this would count for every class - events would not work at all if they would all create new instances?!
Besides this what is a valid solution here?

Comment: Well, websocket is currently not that well integrated with CDI, so that is the issue here (already tracked on spec-level jira). I'm not even sure what you want to do - are your event emitted only for single websocket session or do you want to sent that to all connected clients? Anyway, what you could do is to inject some object to websocket endpoint and set the session there - and then register that object as event listener.

Comment: "already tracked on spec-level jira" could you provide a link please? Meanwhile i did it the way you suggested: i store the project id as user property in session and all sessions are stored in a seesion registry. if event is fired i loop thru sessions and send out message. bad but working and many examples doing it this way too.

Comment: https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-218